# Is there a activation function which can predict most of purely mathematical functions?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I've been trying to build a NN which can predict 1/x for some input x.

Here is the model summary:

```
Model: "sequential_9"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 1000)              2000    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 1000)              1001000   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 1001      

Total params: 1,004,001
Trainable params: 1,004,001
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

I've tried using three Dense layers of relu but the loss is too high. Which activation function should i use. Is it even possible.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
     keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)),
     keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
     keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')
    ]
)
import numpy as np 
n = 10000
x = np.linspace(1,n,n)
y = 1/x
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss="mse")
model.fit(x,y, epochs=500)
```

Comment: Basically every one use ReLU activation nowadays. But you better show more detail, like your code, model setup and the dataset. Predicting 1/x should be very easy for NN.

Comment: I've added the entire code.

Comment: Neural networks may appear magical, but their design does benefit from some basic strategy. In your case, `1/x` can never be greater than 1, and will always be greater than 0; it'll be better to have sigmoid as the activation in the final layer for this purpose. In fact, in this particular case, try sigmoids in `all` layers.

Comment: Also note that this problem is difficult for `any` network since the scales of both inputs and outputs are spread across multiple orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

A network with one hidden layer and relu activation is enough to model any function with whatever precision you like (Universal Approximation Theorem, e.g. see [Michael Nielsen](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html) for a simple description).

That means a function like y(x)=1/x can be modeled with a network which looks like this: `y=W*relu(V*x+a)+b`
where x is the input, V and W are the weights, a and b the bias terms.

When using relu activations, then your output will be created out of line segments.
Of course, using enough of these line segments, you can create an almost perfect approximation of any function.
Given 3 neurons in the hidden layer, we can come up with this very rough approximation for 1/x by hand: `y=1-relu(x/2-1/2)+relu(3*x/8-3/4)+relu(3*x/32-3/8)`.
It should be easy to identify the parameters V, W, a, b from this.
The approximation is valid for the x range from 1 to 8, see the plot:

[image: approximation of 1/x using a neural network]

Usually, you define the network and then use a loss function and an optimizer to train it instead of manually coming up with the parameters as shown before. As a loss function, you could use the absolute or the squared error and see how it performs. Also, start in a smaller x range at the beginning, e.g. from 1 to 8 and see what you get before extending that range.